# Using GeoGebra's font from github in an HTML tutorial

Tags: html, css, github, fonts

I am putting together a tutorial (in .html) on how to use GeoGebra, and I would like to have a css style for the text in my tutorial that will be GGB commands. I would like this to match what GGB uses in its input lines. In other words, I would like the text in my lessons denoting GeoGebra input to look identical (in font, size, etc) as the input when using GeoGebra.

Is there a way (in my css file, or in the header of each html file) that would automatically grab the right font that the current release of GGB uses from GGB's repository on github?

Answer (score 0):

They appear to currently be using unmodified (maybe just stripped of unused characters?) versions of [Roboto](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto) and [Roboto Slab](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto+Slab) (specifically the regular weights of each), which you could use through Google Fonts. Downloading and opening 'Geogebra Serif Regular' from their GitHub repo opens a font file literally just named "Roboto Slab".

You may be able to hotlink to their github files for their [sans](https://github.com/geogebra/geogebra/blob/master/web/src/geogebra/resources/font/GeogebraSans-Regular.ttf?raw=true) and [serif](https://github.com/geogebra/geogebra/blob/master/web/src/geogebra/resources/font/GeogebraSerif-Regular.ttf?raw=true) fonts, though if you are selling these tutorials it appears that you **might** be in violation of [their license](http://www.geogebra.org/info/?action=AboutLicense&version=4.4.43.0&date=08%20August%202014), were you to use these exact files.

Seeing as they seem to move their fonts around a fair bit in their folder structure, and rename the files occasionally, I don't think that there is a guaranteed method to pull "whatever font they happen to be using" from their GitHub in any sort of futureproofed way -- if you hardcode those above links, your own fonts may (and eventually will) spontaneously stop working whenever they decide to shunt folders around.

I surmise that the easiest way for you to match their look-and-feel for the near future would be to simply use Roboto / Roboto Slab via Google Fonts.

AFAIK, these are the only fonts they use in the app.